# How to prevent Android Studio from replacing variables in the code with yellow-colored preview of their values?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-15

On the first screenshot Android Studio shows me the IdToken value "653... " which I don't want to see. I have never hardcoded it in this class.

[image]

When I click it, it shows me what I need, i. e. the variable per se (which I typed in the code, how it should be):

[image]

How can I disable these yellow previews? Just to see the code I type, to avoid any confusion..

Comment: That helps, thank you! File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding -> String References.

Comment: One more step - after changing settings need to restart the Android Studio